# How to call in C lua modules

Tags: lua

To simplify things, let's assume, that there are two Lua scripts, one program and one module, e.g:

sample.lua

```
local sample = {}
    sample.fun1 = function()
    end;
return sample;
```

I'm using it in program, like this:

program.lua

```
local sample = require("sample");
sample.fun1();
```

And now i'm trying to use the same module in C (first running lua program, what is important here), something like this:

```
luaL_dofile(luaState, "program.lua");
...
lua_getglobal(luaState, "sample");
lua_getfield(luaState,-1, "fun1");
```

or

```
luaL_dofile(luaState, "program.lua");
...
lua_getglobal(luaState, "sample.fun1");
```

But both versions causing crash. My question here: Is it possible to use somehow module, which was previously used in program? For this example it is of course nonsense, but my system is far more complicated and i need this functionality. Maybe some other approach to achieve this?

Comment: Either use `luaL_requiref` or read directly `package.loaded.sample`

Comment: Thanks for answer. After short investigation, it is enough to change:  
`local sample = require("sample");  
to:  
`sample = require("sample");  
and use:  
`lua_getglobal(luaState, "sample");  
lua_getfield(luaState,-1, "fun1");